# Exception to declare SyndicationFeed 'Element is an invalid XmlNodeType'

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This is my code :

```
public void GetDatas(String url)  
{
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/fluxRSS.xml");
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items) {
            String t = item.Title.Text;
            String o = item.Summary.Text;
            String p = item.Content.Type;
        }
}
```

When I use the debugger, I've an error on the line `SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);`. The error is "Element is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 2798, position 4"

From the 2798th line in the XML file, I've the following lines:

```xml
<channel>
    <title>Actualités</title>
    <link>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr</link>
    <image>
       <title>Actualités</title>
       <link>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr</link>
       <url>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/medias/clipart/info_big.png</url>
    </image>
    <description>les dernières news du site</description>
    <item>
       <title>Lancement du site !</title>
       <link>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/forum/voirtopic.php?t=13</link>
       <description>ça y est, lebruitdufrigo.fr est en ligne, avec de belles recettes communautaires pour commencer. Cela dit, elles sont encore peu nombreuses, alors lebruitdufrigo a besoin de vos talents de cuisiniers et d\'écrivains pour en ajouter de nouvelles ! Ainsi plus il y aura de recettes, plus la recherche exclusive sera pertinente, c\'est un des principaux intérêts du site...&lt;br /&gt;&#13;Alors n\'hésitez pas, étoffez la base de données et parlez-en au monde entier !&lt;br /&gt;&#13;&lt;br /&gt;&#13; Ben, administrateur du site</description>
        <pubDate>Fri, 09 Nov 2012 19:35:52 +0100</pubDate>
     </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Syndication XML Specification, and examined your XML to see if you are violating the specification?

Comment: Which line is line 2798?

Comment: the line 2798 is the first line

Comment: That doesn't seem likely.  Character 4 in the first line (`'a'`) is unremarkable.  Maybe you should show us a few lines prior to that, since the lines following the failed one are not relevant.

Comment: Please note if you remain only one any channel all works fine, so you can create remain two channels with two items and the error will be the same.

Comment: Is anyone can test my code ?

Comment: I've found where is the error. Actually, it doesn't like when there are more than one "channel" tag in the rss feed.